# Spring inject Repository mixed with normal property in constructor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have `Service` class and `Repository` interface (Spring Data). I have also one abstract class:

```
public abstract class TestingMethod {
    public TestingMethod() {
        timeSum = 0;
    }
    protected long timeSum;
}
```

And class that extends it:

```
@Component
public class LimitTestingMethod extends TestingMethod {

    @Autowired
    private GeoTestDataRepository geoTestDataRepository;

    private final int limitSize;

    public LimitTestingMethod(int limitSize) {
        super();
        this.limitSize = limitSize;
    }
}
```

In my `Service` I want to create instance of `LimitTestingMethod` and set its argument `limitSize`.
Something like:

```
LimitTestingMethod ltm3 = new LimitTestingMethod(3);
LimitTestingMethod ltm10 = new LimitTestingMethod(10);
```

But I got error:

> Description: Parameter 0 of constructor in
> com.exence.postgiscma.testingMethod.LimitTestingMethod required a bean
> of type 'int' that could not be found. Action: Consider defining a
> bean of type 'int' in your configuration.

Is that possible to achieve something like I want?

All best!

//EDIT

As I can see in comments it's bad approach. So maybe someone will give me advise how to project this better?
Is this good solution to pass repo as argument in constructor (I guess that not, but I can't get the idea how to do this better)?

```
LimitTestingMethod ltm3 = new LimitTestingMethod(3, geoTestDataRepository);
```

Is there a good and elegant solution?

Comment: A core concept of Spring is Inversion of Control, where the container is responsible for the creation of each component. By annotating a class as `@Component` you are instructing Spring to create an instance of your class. However, you have not provided any instruction on a value that should be provided for the construction of the bean. Hence the error, what value should spring inject into the constructor.

Comment: Why do you want to create `LimitTestingMethod` with new? Can you get the limitesSize value from a property file maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are creating instances outside the scope of Spring your current solution won't work. The error comes from the fact that you have annotated it with `@Component`, it will detect it at startup and tries to create a bean, and fails.

To solve this you can do 1 of 2 things.

1. Let Spring handle the creation of the beans by using the `ApplicationContext` as a factory, providing additional arguments **and** make the bean prototype scoped.
2. Let Spring handle the injection **after** you manually created the instance using the `ApplicationContext`.

### Use `ApplicationContext` as a factory

First make your bean a prototype so that it will be constructed when needed.

```java
@Component
@Scope(
ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class LimitTestingMethod extends TestingMethod { ... }
```

Now an instance won't be created during startup. In your service inject the `ApplicationContext` and use the `getBean` method to get your desired instance.

```java
public class Service {

  @Autowired
  private ApplicationContext ctx;


  public void yourMethod() {

    LimitTestingMethod ltm3 = ctx.getBean(LimitTestingMethod.class, 3);
    LimitTestingMethod ltm10 = ctx.getBean(LimitTestingMethod.class, 10);

  }
}
```

This will let Spring create the instance using the value passed in for the constructor and do the autowiring.

### Injection after creation

Another solution is to manually create the instances and after that let Spring handle the auto wiring. You will lose the AOP abilities with this and will get only auto wiring.

First remove the `@Component` annotation from your `LimitTestingMethod` so it won't get detected during startup.

```java
public class LimitTestingMethod extends TestingMethod { ... }
```

Now in your service autowire the `ApplicationContext` and after creating your bean use that to inject the dependencies.

```java
public class Service {

  @Autowired
  private ApplicationContext ctx;


  public void yourMethod() {

    LimitTestingMethod ltm3 = new LimitTestingMethod(3);
    LimitTestingMethod ltm10 = new LimitTestingMethod(10);

    ctx.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(lmt3);
    ctx.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(lmt10);

  }
}
```

Both will achieve what you want, however, now your code directly depends on the Spring API. So instead of doing this, you are probably better of with another option and that is to inject everything for the `LimitTestingMethod` through the constructor and pass the repository yourself.

### Use constructor to create an instance

```java
public class LimitTestingMethod extends TestingMethod {

    private final GeoTestDataRepository geoTestDataRepository;
    private final int limitSize;

    public LimitTestingMethod(int limitSize, GeoTestDataRepository geoTestDataRepository) {
      this.limitSize=limitSize;
      this.geoTestDataRepository=geoTestDataRepository;
    }
}
```

Then you can simply autowire the repository in your service class and create the instances as needed (or create a factory which contains the complexity of creating this object).

```java
public class Service {

  @Autowired
  private GeoTestDataRepository repo;


  public void yourMethod() {

    LimitTestingMethod ltm3 = new LimitTestingMethod(3, repo);
    LimitTestingMethod ltm10 = new LimitTestingMethod(10, repo);

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tough that option 3 won't be elegant and the best solution. I think also that there shouldn't be @Autowired annotation, but it's mistake that probably occurred during copying of code.

Comment: Why shouldn't ther be an autowired? How else are you going to get the repository or `ApplicationContext` into your service (although for the latter you could implement `ApplicationContextAware` if you really wanted).

Comment: I mean @Autowired annotation in LimitTestingMethod in last example. Repository is passed there through constructor.